# what is this .next() and what is the iterator ? leetcode 284

Tags: python, iterator

Trying out "LeetCode 284.  Peeking Iterator": https://leetcode.com/problems/peeking-iterator/

[image]

Reference the solution:

```
01. class PeekingIterator(object):
02.     def __init__(self, iterator):
03.         self.iter = iterator
04.         self.temp = self.iter.next() if self.iter.hasNext() else None
05. 
06.     def peek(self):
07.         return self.temp
08. 
09.    def next(self):
10.        ret = self.temp
11.        self.temp = self.iter.next() if self.iter.hasNext() else None
12.        return ret
13.
14.    def hasNext(self):
15.        return self.temp is not None
```

I have 2 questions:

1. line 4: `self.iter.next()`.  Is the `.next()` referring to the method in `line 9` ?  I tried to put print statements but find that the print statements is only invoked when the `line 9 def next(self):` is called by Leetcode but not by `line 4`.  So it seems to me like the `.next()` is a Python built-in iterator function.  But there isn't such a function.  That's why I'm puzzled.  On top of that, if it's the method in `line 9`, it would be called iteratively but it does not seems to do so (looking at the print statements).
2. 2nd question is more complicated. The input to creating the class at `line 2` is [[1,2,3]]

[image]

This is a Python list.  Yet inside the `__init__`, I could not do a iterator[0] nor a `next(iterator)`.  So I'm puzzled by why this is the case.  I get the following errors:

[image]
[image]

But I can do `print(f'{iterator.next()=}')`

[image]

So my 2nd question is what exactly is being received by `__init__`.  It's not a list and a iterator.

Sorry for my long question.  I hope I've explain my question clearly enough.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: @luk2302 it's a valid question. Try running `iter(range(3)).next()` and see what happens. My guess is that there's an `Iterator` class separately defined. It's an implementation detail in the problem

Comment: Where did that "solution" come from?  It looks like Java code that was mechanically translated to Python, without caring about the fact that *iterators work differently in the two languages*.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter

Comment: @PatrickHaugh the `Iterator` in this case is not the same as a python iterator

Comment: @C.Nivs you are guessing what `Iterator` is - the fact that it is not specified or even mentioned in the question means this post is lacking detail.

Comment: @luk2302 I don't think that's the fault of OP, that's the fault of Leetcode. Leetcode has defined something called `Iterator` that does not behave as such in python. My response to you was in regards to needing to review how iterators work, which would not have helped OP with this question

Comment: @luke2302 - it is mentioned: "__Note:__ Each language may have it's own implementation of the constructor and `Iterator`..."

Comment: @C.Nivs It does behave as an iterator, just not the one built-in to Python. Leetcode problem is clearly supposed to be language-agnostic, so it chose interface as consistant as possible between different languages instead of getting into specifics of each language.

Comment: Then what is the confusion about if the assignment clearly states what is happening. There is an `Iterator` and it has a `.next()` method. Assuming you can pass it to `next(...)` itself or having a subscript on it is just wrong because nobody specified it to exist.

Comment: @luk2302, well, that is the point of the question - OP most likely didn't realise the existence of this `Iterator`

Comment: Hi all.  I did check what iterator is.  I check the input to __init__() and its a list.  So I should be able to do a iterator[0] but I cannot.  That's why I find it so confusing.

Comment: @EBDS How did you verify that `__init__` got a list as its argument?

Comment: @matszwecja I saw it in the example [1,2,3], so I guess I've assumed (wrongly).  I did try to do a print(type(iterator)) and I got a `<class '__main__.Iterator'>` as my output.  It was my mistake that I didn't notice this. At that time, I was really confused by the unexpected behaviour and the different outcome I got on my laptop.  It's really something new to me.  It's good that I've unraveled the mystery. And thanks both of you for the answers...

Comment: Thanks to all for the constructive help given to me.  I understand why now.  I've learnt something useful which is the most important outcome of asking the question.  Again, thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the code in question implements its own `Iterator` class that has `.next()` method and converts `[1,2,3]` input to an instance of this class. This is also what `self.iter.next()` in line 4 is calling. You've got to work with the interface you are given.

This custom class is the reason `next(iterator)` doesn't work (as sit does not implement `__iter__` and `__next__` methods) as well as `iterator[0]` (as it's no longer input array)
It implements `iterator.next()`, just like your `PeekingIterator` is supposed to.

Comment: Why I'm confused is that it's clear from the input, a list was sent to the __init__(). So won't I be able to do a iterator[0] ?

Answer (score 1):

What you get is an `Iterator`, which has absolutely nothing to do with python `iterator`s, they could have (and maybe should have) called it `ClassWithNextAndHasNextMethods`. You receive an instance of that class into your `__init__`.

No, `self.iter.next()` is not referring to line 9, `self.next()` would do that. `self.iter.next()` is calling the `next()` method on the thing that was passed into the constructor.

Comment: Why I'm confused is that it's clear from the input, a list was sent to the __init__().  So won't I be able to do a iterator[0] ?

Comment: @EBDS No, the list wasn't sent to the `__init__` of PeekingIterator (well, not directly). There is step not visible to you that creates instance of `Iterator` from the input list, and **that** is what is passed to PeekingIterator `__init__`

Comment: @EBDS I'll say, the part in Explanation is a bit confusing, as it doesn't show that extra step of conversion from list to Iterator.

Comment: @EBDS what you see there is pseudo-code (or the Java equivalent) which could not be valid python anyway. You do not start with the type of the variable, you do not have `new`. The python would be `peekingIterator = PeekingIterator(...)`.

Comment: @matszwecja Oh.... I'm getting it.  The example code is not in Python.  (=> it has a new to create an instance).   So the implementation for Python is not as shown in the example. wow.  Something I need to take note of.  Now I understand why I have a different behaviour on my laptop.  I'm getting it... need to get use to this idea.  Thanks....very much.

Comment: Actually, if you check the problem definition on LeetCode, you will notice that there is the following in the solution template: `# Your PeekingIterator object will be instantiated and called as such: iter = PeekingIterator(Iterator(nums))`. The comments on such sites are usually there for a reason, and reading them could have saved you the whole question.

Comment: @matszwecja I did read but I didn't understand what it means. Now I'm getting it.